# Caching/storing twitter API data in MySQL db

Tags: twitter

I have a database of twitter usernames in a mysql DB. I would like to populate the currently empty description, location and url fields with data.

What would be be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the Twitter [REST API documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/REST+API+Documentation). There should be something in there you can use.

For example, if you use the following url, you get information in JSON format on a particular user: `http://twitter.com/users/show/<userid>.json`. If you end your url with `.xml` instead of `.json`, you get the same info in xml format.

Then in your application you can parse the returned data and add the missing values to your database.